# React native get information from json data

Tags: reactjs, graphics, native, react-native-flatlist

I'm a beginner in react native, so, what I wanted to do is to get an item.CPU in an array to be able to put it in sampleData so I can render the information in a graphic using PureChart.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator, SafeAreaView, FlatList, Text, View } from 
'react-native';
import PureChart from 'react-native-pure-chart';
export default class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {data: []};
}

componentDidMount() {
  fetch('http://192.168.1.34:3000/users').then((response) => 
response.json()).then((json)=> this.setState({data : json.param})).catch((error) => 
 console.error(error));
}

render() {
const { data } = this.state;
let sampleData = [30, 200, 170, 250, 10];
return (

  <View style = {styles.container}>
  <PureChart  data={sampleData} type='line' />
  <SafeAreaView >
  <FlatList data ={data} keyExtractor={({ID}, index) => ID} renderItem={({item})=>(<Text>{item.CPU}</Text>)}/>
  </SafeAreaView>
  </View>

  // <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
  //     <FlatList
  //       data={data}
  //       keyExtractor={({ ID }, index) => ID}
  //       renderItem={({ item }) => (<Text>{item.CPU}, {item.RPM}</Text>)}
  //     />
  //
  
   );
  }
   };

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
  top: "50%",
  },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to pass in the json data inside a prop. You should make this request before you load the view. That way you remove potential bugs that arise from things like server errors, errors from improperly handling loading  etc.

Comment: And how can i do that ?